# If... else condition in LUA language

Tags: if-statement, lua, love2d

I'm new to coding and I recently started to take my baby steps in LUA. I have a small problem so it would be very helpful if you can help me. In my code, I need to code that
`If x ~= 1 and x~=2 and x~=3 and x~=4 then (do something) end`
is there a faster way not to hardcode that part, not to type the whole thing from x~=1 to x~=4?
Thank you!

Comment: `if x > 4 then`

Comment: `local t={[1]=true, [2]=true, [3]=true, [4]=true}; if not t[x] then...`

Answer (score 1):

If you need something like `if x ~= 1 and x~=2 and x~=3 and x~=4 then (do something) end`  x is usually an integer.

Then

```
if x < 1 or x > 4 then
  -- do your stuff here
end
```

Is what you are looking for. If you want to explicitly check wether x is unquald 1,2,3,4 you can simply do something like Egor suggested.

But as you see unless you can describe your conditions in a shorter mathematical way you still have separate unique conditions and you won't come around writing them down.

If you have to check those conditions repeatedly you can use a truth table like in Egor's example or you write a function that returns if that condition is met for its argument.

Comment: Your second example does the stuff four times though ;)

Comment: removed. thanks, looks like I had a stroke yesterday